# AMD Radeon Driver Purgatory

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, 21.04

I am using Ubuntu 21.04 and I wanted to install OpenCL in order to mine. After accidentally installing the AMD pro driver and then uninstalling it, I am now left without any driver, as reported by `sudo lshw -c video`:

```
*-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Renoir
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       version: ce
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:fc0-fbf iomemory:fc0-fbf memory:fce0000000-fcefffffff memory:fcf0000000-fcf01fffff ioport:1000(size=256) memory:d0400000-d047ffff
```

My question is, there was a driver installed by default, so how do I get that one back? I have tried

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

as well as

```
sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

followed by rebooting, but nothing has worked.

I've also tried to install `amdgpu` both through the installer provided by AMD and through apt, but keep getting the error:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of amdgpu:
  amdgpu depends on amdgpu-dkms (= 1:5.9.20.104-1247438); however:
  Package amdgpu-dkms is not configured yet.
```

But trying to install `amdgpu-dkms` gives a similar error.

From what I've read, the official AMD drivers aren't supported with my kernel version, but I should be able to revert to the original default driver, right? I also found someone who had success with 21.04 with just installing OpenCL over the default [here](https://dazeb.uk/how-to-install-amd-opencl-gpu-drivers-on-ubuntu-21-04-for-mining-ethereum/).

`grep -E 'amdgpu|radeon' /etc/modprobe.d/*` gives

```
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-amdgpu.conf:blacklist amdgpu
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-framebuffer.conf:blacklist radeonfb
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-radeon.conf:blacklist radeon
```

Comment: Probably you have blacklisted the default kernel module. The unclear part is what is the GPU and how did you install the pro driver. Also output of `grep -E 'amdgpu|radeon' /etc/modprobe.d/*` may give some clue.

Comment: @Pilot6 Yes, there are 3 entries there: `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-amdgpu.conf:blacklist amdgpu
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-framebuffer.conf:blacklist radeonfb
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-radeon.conf:blacklist radeon`. The GPU is integrated Radeon graphics with Ryzen 4500U. And I installed the pro driver following this: https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/faq/amdgpu-installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`amdgpu` module is blacklisted. Remove it by

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-amdgpu.conf
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

and reboot.

`radeon` is also blacklisted, but it doesn't make any difference for your GPU, but you can delete that file too.

Comment: It worked! I'm not sure how it got blacklisted.... but thanks!

Comment: Hey @Pilot6, I'm having a different problem now. I tried to install OpenCL using `./amdgpu-install --opencl=legacy --headless --no-dkms` and it appears to have worked, but `clinfo` reveals that I have 0 devices available, and it also gives a message saying that `libamdocl64.so` is missing. Do you have any ideas by any chance?